# Exporting virtual raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, multi-band

I have multispectral images collected from parrot sequoia. I want to merge all 4 different bands and create a single .tif file. I created the virtual raster layer with all the bands included in that, however when I export that virtual raster as .tif file it converts the 1st band into the grey band. Can anyone tell me how to avoid this? I even tried merge raster option it is still doing the same.

Comment: The gdalbuildvrt utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html has an option `-separate`. And the QGIS merge tool seems to have on option "Place each input file into a separate band".

Comment: I exported it by selecting the option "Place each input file into a separate band" still having the same problem

Comment: What is the problem actually? Do you get a single band output or a 4 band output but with 1st band labeled as grayscale?

Comment: I am getting 4 band output but with 1st band labelled as grey

Comment: Ok, you could clarify that in your question. And what kind of images you have as a source? Do you have 4 single band images as source and you combine them into 4 band with vrt?